# I don't display what I want with mediaquery (min-height max-height), ok with width?

Tags: css, xpages

I have several mediaqueries. It's works perfectly with the width and it's awfull with height... !!?

I put the same code but.. All the width are ok.

```
    @media all and (max-width: 800px)
{               
    .customTips
    {
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        top: 950px;
        width: auto; 
    }

}   

@media all and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 920px) 
{
    .customTips
    {
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        top: 950px;
        width: auto; 
    }       
}

@media all and (min-width: 921px) and (max-width: 1320px)
{               
    .customTips
    {       
        width: 15%;
    }       
}
```

The code with height doesnt' works correctly.

```
@media all  and (min-height: 720px) and (max-height: 767px)
    {       
        .customCadreFormulaire
        {
            height: 405px !important;
        }       
    }

    @media all  and (min-height: 768px) and (max-height: 899px)
    {               
        .customCadreFormulaire
        {
            height: 420px !important;
        }   
    }
```

When I try this code, with a screen 1440/900, the code for media all  and (min-height: 720px) and (max-height: 767px) works at place ??
I don't understand why, an idea ? Thanks..

Comment: I don't think this should affect functionality but you have two spaces between "all" and "and" in the height media queries

Comment: I don't think this is related to XPages - unless CSS fights with your theme (and you didn't say which one you use). Did you chceck browser's devtools what CSS definition is active (from what CSS file)?

Comment: Is .customCadreFormulaire defined in your CSS elsewhere?

Comment: @jonas Grumann : I modified the space, no change ^^.

Comment: Per Henrik Lausten : I have several object with the class customCadreFormulaire. Frantisek Kossuth : I think so it isn't related to XPages. I use Oneuibleu IBM theme. I use a specified css file named custom.css.